# Error showing at tAccessInput component

Tags: talend

While using tAccessInput component in my job, it showing error like,

```
It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.
```

But, it all the connections and database/table names are valid in my job.
What can be the problem. and how can i resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metioning the exact DBVersion is more important for tAccessInput/tAccessOutput.
Like Access 2003/Access 2007 and associated database file name.

[image]